# Google Translate API - Error code 400

Tags: google-api, google-translate

So I'm getting an error code 400 with a `keyInvalid` reason:

```
     json = {
    error =     {
        code = 400;
        errors =         (
                        {
                domain = usageLimits;
                message = "Bad Request";
                reason = keyInvalid;
            }
        );
        message = "Bad Request";
    };
}
```

[image]

I'm using the correct API call I'm sure:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&q=hello%20world&source=en&target=de
```

And for `INSERT-YOUR-KEY` I've tried both the `Client ID` and the `Client secret`.

Also, I do have the Translate API turned on in the console.

Comment: So, I'm using just the API call I pasted above. I'm not going through OAuth and requesting an access token first. Is that what's missing?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Oh lord, what a waste of time - mostly my fault! So I needed to create a public API key, which was the second option on the page staring right in the face this whole time. One of those days...